# Is Ruby's code block same as C#'s lambda expression?

Tags: c#, ruby

Are these two essentially the same thing? They look very similar to me.

Did lambda expression borrow its idea from Ruby?

Comment: Lambda expressions borrow from the lambda calculus of the 1930s, and ML of the 70s.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ruby actually has 4 constructs that are all extremely similar

### The Block

The idea behind blocks is sort of a way to implement really light weight strategy patterns. A block will define a coroutine on the function, which the function can delegate control to with the yield keyword. We use blocks for just about everything in ruby, including pretty much all the looping constructs or anywhere you would use `using` in c#. Anything outside the block is in scope for the block, however the inverse is not true, with the exception that return inside the block will return the outer scope. They look like this

```
def foo
  yield 'called foo'
end

#usage
foo {|msg| puts msg} #idiomatic for one liners

foo do |msg| #idiomatic for multiline blocks
  puts msg
end
```

### Proc

A proc is basically taking a block and passing it around as a parameter. One extremely interesting use of this is that you can pass a proc in as a replacement for a block in another method. Ruby has a special character for proc coercion which is &, and a special rule that if the last param in a method signature starts with an &, it will be a proc representation of the block for the method call. Finally, there is a builtin method called `block_given?`, which will return true if the current method has a block defined. It looks like this

```
def foo(&block)
  return block
end

b = foo {puts 'hi'}
b.call # hi
```

To go a little deeper with this, there is a really neat trick that rails added to Symbol (and got merged into core ruby in 1.9). Basically, that & coercion does its magic by calling `to_proc` on whatever it is next to. So the rails guys added a Symbol#to_proc that would call itself on whatever is passed in. That lets you write some really terse code for any aggregation style function that is just calling a method on every object in a list

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'this is from bar'
  end
end

list = [Foo.new, Foo.new, Foo.new]

list.map {|foo| foo.bar} # returns ['this is from bar', 'this is from bar', 'this is from bar']
list.map &:bar # returns _exactly_ the same thing
```

More advanced stuff, but imo that really illustrates the sort of magic you can do with procs

### Lambdas

The purpose of a lambda is pretty much the same in ruby as it is in c#, a way to create an inline function to either pass around, or use internally. Like blocks and procs, lambdas are closures, but unlike the first two it enforces arity, and return from a lambda exits the lambda, not the containing scope. You create one by passing a block to the lambda method, or to -> in ruby 1.9

```
l = lambda {|msg| puts msg} #ruby 1.8
l = -> {|msg| puts msg} #ruby 1.9

l.call('foo') # => foo
```

### Methods

Only serious ruby geeks really understand this one :) A method is a way to turn an existing function into something you can put in a variable. You get a method by calling the `method` function, and passing in a symbol as the method name. You can re bind a method, or you can coerce it into a proc if you want to show off. A way to re-write the previous method would be

```
l = lambda &method(:puts)
l.call('foo')
```

What is happening here is that you are creating a method for puts, coercing it into a proc, passing that in as a replacement for a block for the lambda method, which in turn returns you the lambda

---

Feel free to ask about anything that isn't clear (writing this really late on a weeknight without an irb, hopefully it isn't pure gibberish)

EDIT: To address questions in the comments

> list.map &:bar Can I use this syntax
>   with a code block that takes more than
>   one argument? Say I have hash = { 0 =>
>   "hello", 1 => "world" }, and I want to
>   select the elements that has 0 as the
>   key. Maybe not a good example. – Bryan
>   Shen

Gonna go kind of deep here, but to really understand how it works you need to understand how ruby method calls work.

Basically, ruby doesn't have a concept of invoking a method, what happens is that objects pass messages to each other. The `obj.method arg` syntax you use is really just sugar around the more explicit form, which is `obj.send :method, arg`, and is functionally equivalent to the first syntax. This is a fundamental concept in the language, and is why things like `method_missing` and `respond_to?` make sense, in the first case you are just handling an unrecognized message, the second you are checking to see if it is listening for that message.

The other thing to know is the rather esoteric "splat" operator, `*`. Depending on where its used, it actually does very different things.

```
def foo(bar, *baz)
```

In a method call, if it is the last parameter, splat will make that parameter glob up all additional parameters passed in to the function (sort of like `params` in C#)

```
obj.foo(bar, *[biz, baz])
```

When in a method call (or anything else that takes argument lists), it will turn an array into a bare argument list. The snippet below is equivilent to the snippet above.

```
obj.foo(bar, biz, baz)
```

Now, with `send` and `*` in mind, `Symbol#to_proc` is basically implemented like this

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

So, `&:sym` is going to make a new proc, that calls `.send :sym` on the first argument passed to it. If any additional args are passed, they are globbed up into an array called `args`, and then splatted into the `send` method call.

> I notice that & is used in three
>   places: def foo(&block), list.map
>   &:bar, and l = lambda &method(:puts).
>   Do they share the same meaning? –
>   Bryan Shen

Yes, they do. An & will call `to_proc` on what ever it is beside. In the case of the method definition it has a special meaning when on the last parameter, where you are pulling in the co-routine defined as a block, and turning that into a proc. Method definitions are actually one of the most complex parts of the language, there are a huge amount of tricks and special meanings that can be in the parameters, and the placement of the parameters.

> b = {0 => "df", 1 => "kl"} p b.select
>   {|key, value| key.zero? } I tried to
>   transform this to p b.select &:zero?,
>   but it failed. I guess that's because
>   the number of parameters for the code
>   block is two, but &:zero? can only
>   take one param. Is there any way I can
>   do that? – Bryan Shen

This should be addressed earlier, unfortunately you can't do it with this trick.

> "A method is a way to turn an existing
>   function into something you can put in
>   a variable." why is l = method(:puts)
>   not sufficient? What does lambda &
>   mean in this context? – Bryan Shen

That example was exceptionally contrived, I just wanted to show equivalent code to the example before it, where I was passing a proc to the `lambda` method. I will take some time later and re-write that bit, but you are correct, `method(:puts)` is totally sufficient. What I was trying to show is that you can use `&method(:puts)` anywhere that would take a block. A better example would be this

```
['hello', 'world'].each &method(:puts) # => hello\nworld
```

> l = -> {|msg| puts msg} #ruby 1.9:
>   this doesn't work for me. After I
>   checked Jörg's answer, I think it
>   should be l = -> (msg) {puts msg}. Or
>   maybe i'm using an incorrect version
>   of Ruby? Mine is ruby 1.9.1p738 –
>   Bryan Shen

Like I said in the post, I didn't have an irb available when I was writing the answer, and you are right, I goofed that (spend the vast majority of my time in 1.8.7, so I am not used to the new syntax yet)

There is no space between the stabby bit and the parens. Try `l = ->(msg) {puts msg}`. There was actually a lot of resistance to this syntax, since it is so different from everything else in the language.

Comment: Your last example is *not* an `UnboundMethod` , it's a `Method`. `UnboundMethod` s are, well, methods that aren't bound to any `self` . They are created with the `Module#instance_method` family of methods. They need to be bound to a receiver first, which will convert them to a `Method` which can then be called. BTW: why not just do `l = method(:puts)` in that last example? Why unwrap the `Method` into a block, then re-wrap into a `Proc` if what you want to do is demonstrate how `Method`s work?

Comment: @Jörg: you are totally right about the unbound method thing. The last example was that way because I wanted to demonstrate a common use of the function, although its probably a bit too contrived to be useful. I will rewrite the last bit later

Comment: Excellent writeup! Thank you very much! It's even better than I can get from a Ruby text book.

Comment: `list.map &:bar`  Can I use this syntax with a code block that takes more than one argument? Say I have `hash = { 0 => "hello", 1 => "world" }`, and I want to select the elements that has 0 as the key. Maybe not a good example.

Comment: I notice that `&` is used in three places: `def foo(&block)`, `list.map &:bar`, and `l = lambda &method(:puts)`. Do they share the same meaning?

Comment: `b = {0 => "df", 1 => "kl"} p b.select {|key, value| key.zero? }`  I tried to transform this to `p b.select &:zero?`, but it failed. I guess that's because the number of parameters for the code block is two, but &:zero? can only take one param. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: "A method is a way to turn an existing function into something you can put in a variable."  why is `l = method(:puts)` not sufficient? What does `lambda &` mean in this context?

Comment: `l = -> {|msg| puts msg} #ruby 1.9`: this doesn't work for me. After I checked Jörg's answer, I think it should be `l = -> (msg) {puts msg}`. Or maybe i'm using an incorrect version of Ruby? Mine is ruby 1.9.1p738

Answer (score 35):

## C# vs. Ruby

> Are these two essentially the same thing? They look very similar to me.

They are very different.

First off, lambdas in C# do two *very* different things, only one of which has an equivalent in Ruby. (And that equivalent is, surprise, lambdas, not blocks.)

In C#, lambda expression literals are overloaded. (Interestingly, they are the *only* overloaded literals, as far as I know.) And they are overloaded on their *result type*. (Again, they are the *only* thing in C# that can be overloaded on its result type, methods can only be overloaded on their argument types.)

C# lambda expression literals can *either* be an anonymous piece of executable code *or* an *abstract representation* of an anonymous piece of executable code, depending on whether their result type is `Func` / `Action` or `Expression`.

Ruby doesn't have any equivalent for the latter functionality (well, there are interpreter-specific non-portable non-standardized extensions). And the equivalent for the former functionality is a lambda, not a block.

The Ruby syntax for a lambda is very similar to C#:

```
->(x, y) { x + y }           # Ruby
(x, y) => { return x + y; } // C#
```

In C#, you can drop the `return`, the semicolon and the curly braces if you only have a single expression as the body:

```
->(x, y) { x + y }  # Ruby
(x, y) => x + y    // C#
```

You can leave off the parentheses if you have only one parameter:

```
-> x { x }  # Ruby
x => x     // C#
```

In Ruby, you can leave off the parameter list if it is empty:

```
-> { 42 }  # Ruby
() => 42  // C#
```

An alternative to using the literal lambda syntax in Ruby is to pass a block argument to the `Kernel#lambda` method:

```
->(x, y) { x + y }
lambda {|x, y| x + y } # same thing
```

The main difference between those two is that you don't know what `lambda` does, since it could be overridden, overwritten, wrapped or otherwise modified, whereas the behavior of literals cannot be modified in Ruby.

In Ruby 1.8, you can also use `Kernel#proc` although you should probably avoid that since that method does something different in 1.9.

Another difference between Ruby and C# is the syntax for *calling* a lambda:

```
l.()  # Ruby
l()  // C#
```

I.e. in C#, you use the same syntax for calling a lambda that you would use for calling anything else, whereas in Ruby, the syntax for calling a method is different from the syntax for calling any other kind of callable object.

Another difference is that in C#, `()` is built into the language and is only available for certain builtin types like methods, delegates, `Action`s and `Func`s, whereas in Ruby, `.()` is simply syntactic sugar for `.call()` and can thus be made to work with *any* object by just implementing a `call` method.

## procs vs. lambdas

So, what *are* lambdas exactly? Well, they are instances of the `Proc` class. Except there's a slight complication: there are actually two different kinds of instances of the `Proc` class which are subtly different. (IMHO, the `Proc` class should be split into two classes for the two different kinds of objects.)

In particular, not all `Proc`s are lambdas. You can check whether a `Proc` is a lambda by calling the `Proc#lambda?` method. (The usual convention is to call lambda `Proc`s "lambdas" and non-lambda `Proc`s just "procs".)

Non-lambda procs are created by passing a block to `Proc.new` or to `Kernel#proc`. However, note that before Ruby 1.9, `Kernel#proc` creates a *lambda*, not a proc.

What's the difference? Basically, lambdas behave more like methods, procs behave more like blocks.

If you have followed some of the discussions on the Project Lambda for Java 8 mailinglists, you might have encountered the problem that it is not at all clear how non-local control-flow should behave with lambdas. In particular, there are three possible sensible behaviors for `return` (well, three *possible* but only two are really *sensible*) in a lambda:

- return from the lambda
- return from the method the lambda was called from
- return from the method the lambda was created in

That last one is a bit iffy, since in general the method will have *already* returned, but the other two both make perfect sense, and neither is more right or more obvious than the other. The current state of Project Lambda for Java 8 is that they use two different keywords (`return` and `yield`). Ruby uses the two different kinds of `Proc`s:

- procs return from the calling method (just like blocks)
- lambdas return from the lambda (just like methods)

They also differ in how they handle argument binding. Again, lambdas behave more like methods and procs behave more like blocks:

- you can pass more arguments to a proc than there are parameters, in which case the excess arguments will be ignored
- you can pass less arguments to a proc than there are parameters, in which case the excess parameters will be bound to `nil`
- if you pass a *single* argument which is an `Array` (or responds to `to_ary`) and the proc has multiple parameters, the array will be unpacked and the elements bound to the parameters (exactly like they would in the case of destructuring assignment)

## Blocks: lightweight procs

A block is essentially a lightweight proc. *Every* method in Ruby has *exactly one* block parameter, which does not actually appear in its parameter list (more on that later), i.e. is implicit. This means that on *every* method *call* you can pass a block argument, whether the method expects it or not.

Since the block doesn't appear in the parameter list, there is no name you can use to refer to it. So, how do you use it? Well, the only two things you can do (not really, but more on that later) is *call* it implicitly via the `yield` keyword and check whether a block was passed via `block_given?`. (Since there is no name, you cannot use the `call` or `nil?` methods. What would you call them on?)

Most Ruby implementations implement blocks in a very lightweight manner. In particular, they don't actually implement them as objects. However, since they have no name, you cannot refer to them, so it's actually impossible to tell whether they *are* objects or not. You can just think of them as procs, which makes it easier since there is one less different concept to keep in mind. Just treat the fact that they aren't actually implemented as blocks as a compiler optimization.

## `to_proc` and `&`

There *is* actually a way to refer to a block: the `&` sigil / modifier / unary prefix operator. It can only appear in parameter lists and argument lists.

In a *parameter list*, it means "*wrap up* the implicit block into a proc and bind it to this name". In an *argument list*, it means "*unwrap* this `Proc` into a block".

```
def foo(&bar)
end
```

Inside the method, `bar` is now bound to a proc object that represents the block. This means for example that you can store it in an instance variable for later use.

```
baz(&quux)
```

In this case, `baz` is actually a method which takes zero arguments. But of course it takes the implicit block argument which all Ruby methods take. We are passing the contents of the variable `quux`, but unroll it into a block first.

This "unrolling" actually works not just for `Proc`s. `&` calls `to_proc` on the object first, to convert it to a proc. That way, *any* object can be converted into a block.

The most widely used example is `Symbol#to_proc`, which first appeared sometime during the late 90s, I believe. It became popular when it was added to ActiveSupport from where it spread to Facets and other extension libraries. Finally, it was added to the Ruby 1.9 core library and backported to 1.8.7. It's pretty simple:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    ->(recv, *args) { recv.send self, *args }
  end
end

%w[Hello StackOverflow].map(&:length) # => [5, 13]
```

Or, if you interpret classes as functions for creating objects, you can do something like this:

```
class Class
  def to_proc
    -> *args { new *args }
  end
end

[1, 2, 3].map(&Array) # => [[nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

## `Method`s and `UnboundMethod`s

Another class to represent a piece of executable code, is the `Method` class. `Method` objects are reified proxies for methods. You can create a `Method` object by calling `Object#method` on *any* object and passing the name of the method you want to reify:

```
m = 'Hello'.method(:length)
m.() #=> 5
```

or using the *method reference operator `.:`*:

```
m = 'Hello'.:length
m.() #=> 5
```

`Method`s respond to `to_proc`, so you can pass them anywhere you could pass a block:

```
[1, 2, 3].each(&method(:puts))
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

An `UnboundMethod` is a proxy for a method that hasn't been bound to a receiver yet, i.e. a method for which `self` hasn't been defined yet. You cannot call an `UnboundMethod`, but you can `bind` it to an object (which must be an instance of the module you got the method from), which will convert it to a `Method`.

`UnboundMethod` objects are created by calling one of the methods from the `Module#instance_method` family, passing the name of the method as an argument.

```
u = String.instance_method(:length)

u.()
# NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #<UnboundMethod: String#length>

u.bind(42)
# TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of String

u.bind('Hello').() # => 5
```

## Generalized callable objects

Like I already hinted at above: there's not much special about `Proc`s and `Method`s. *Any* object that responds to `call` can be called and *any* object that responds to `to_proc` can be converted to a `Proc` and thus unwrapped into a block and passed to a method which expects a block.

## History

> Did lambda expression borrow its idea from Ruby?

Probably not. Most modern programming languages have some form of anonymous literal block of code: Lisp (1958), Scheme, Smalltalk (1974), Perl, Python, ECMAScript, Ruby, Scala, Haskell, C++, D, Objective-C, even PHP(!). And of course, the whole idea goes back to Alonzo Church's λ-calculus (1935 and even earlier).

Comment: much better answer then mine, +1

Comment: @Matt Briggs: I actually tried to keep our answers mostly orthogonal and complementary. For example, for every construct, you explain how it is used, and I deliberately left that out. There's some duplication around `&`, `to_proc` and `Symbol#to_proc` and a couple of other places, but mostly the two answers stand well on their own.

Comment: Thank you Thank you very much for giving me such a in-depth perspective!!!! It answered several questions I had after reading Matt's post.

Comment: "    * procs return from the calling method (just like blocks)
    * lambdas return from the lambda (just like methods) "   Now I finally understand the difference between those two. :)

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly. But they're very similar. The most obvious difference is that in C# a lambda expression can go anywhere where you might have a value that happens to be a function; in Ruby you only have one code block per method call.

They both borrowed the idea from [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) (a programming language dating back to the late 1950s) which in turn borrowed the lambda concept from [Church's Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), invented in the 1930s.

Comment: oh Lisp... Lots of Irritating Stupid Parenthesis :)

Comment: Of course, Ruby has lambda syntax that allows you to store functions as Proc objects as well.

Comment: Is there a way in ruby to call one function passing in TWO lambda arguments?

Comment: Joel: I think the idea is that you store a lambda into a variable and then you can pass that variable as a parameter to a function.

Comment: that's what I thought. So that defeats the purpose of a lambda as a temporary, throw-away, local, anonymous function *IF* you should ever need to pass TWO of them as arguments to a function. Which rarely happens in practice so it's not a serious limitation of Ruby (just weird imho that code blocks can't be truly first class literals)

Comment: I think this stems from Ruby's use of blocks as control structures like in Smalltalk (Ruby even uses the vertical bars, though Smalltalk lets you use a block anywhere) rather than as function objects like in LISP.

Comment: blocks aren't really used for this, we've got lambdas in ruby too

Comment: @Gabe It doesn't need to be a variable--but a bonafied callable object (e.g. Proc/lambda) and not a block (of which there can be one).

Comment: @Joel Spolsky Blocks are mostly just convenient syntax these days. They are automatically lifted to other callables as needed (`&proc`, for instance). Because a "normal" lambda can be used, there is no limitation, excluding the "idiomatic syntax".