# Do C# closures support non-local returns?

Tags: c#, closures

To explain the matter here is some Scala code:

```
object Scratch {
    def foo: Int = {
        val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
        list.foreach { each =>
            if(each > 2) {
                return each
            }
          println(each)
    }
    return 5   
}


def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val i = foo
    println("i: " + i)   
}
```

The code above prints this to the console:

```
1
2
i: 3
```

In particular, note that the closure used by `list.foreach` has a `return` statement, and this `return` statement causes `foo`, the caller of `list.foreach`, to return, interrupting the `foreach` enumeration and providing the actual return value for `foo`. This `return` is not declared within the `foo` method itself, and so is a "non-local return".

The question is now how the same thing would turn out in C#, e.g. will something else be printed to the console? The question is about non-local returns in C# from inside closures. Only if they are supported the same output would occur as in the code above.

Note: This is no speciality of Scala. Other language have this as well like Smalltalk or Kotlin, probably also Ruby and others for sure.

I wanted to try this out myself, but after downloadinng 9 GB for installing Visual Studio 2017 I was told to upgrade to Windows 10 and that was not what I wanted to do just to get this question answered.

Comment: use LINQPAD, if you want to test small C# codes.

Comment: With the abundance of online editors and lightweight IDEs like LINQPad or VS Code, not wanting to install the IDE is not a reason to not make an attempt yourself.

Comment: Thanks for those hints. I didn't know since I'm not a .NET developer. Nevertheless, the question is of general kind and therefore of general interest.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I'd voted to close and so forgot to retract my vote. Obviously I did eventually figure out what you were asking (it wasn't clear to me at first, but after some pondering I did work it out :) ), and so I should have removed that vote. I've now at least contributed my reopen vote. I've also edited the question to provide the missing clarity that had me confused the first time around.

Comment: I was thinking that non-local returns could be added to a C# project by using Fody (or the new Roslyn APIs) to inline the IL of a lambda function and replace `return` with `goto` (for local returns) and replace `throw new NonLocalReturnException` with `return` for non-local returns and to elide any `try/catch`. I'll throw that idea onto my backlog...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C# does not support non-local returns in closures. A C# closure is a method unto itself, and does not share context (other than captured variables) with its enclosing method. When you return from within a lambda expression, you are returning from *that* method, i.e. the anonymous method the lambda refers to. It doesn't affect the method in which the lambda is declared, nor the method from which the lambda is invoked (if different from that in which it's declared).

I'm not that familiar with either Scala or Ruby, but it appears that Scala is more similar to Ruby than to C#. If so, I take it that non-local returns cause the *calling* method to return. It just happens in your example that the calling method is the same as the declaring method, but for obvious reasons it would be pretty odd for a lambda to cause the declaring method to return. I.e. the lambda might be invoked after the declaring method has already returned. There's more in-depth discussion of Ruby (and by inference, Scala) at the Stack Overflow question [Is Ruby's code block same as C#'s lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331714).

Of course, you can still accomplish the same effect in C#. It's just that the exact syntax you're using won't do that. In .NET, the `List<T>` generic class has a `ForEach()` method, so taking your code example literally (i.e. using that built-in `ForEach()` method), this is the closest you can come in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var i = foo();
    WriteLine($"i: {i}");
}

static int foo()
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    try
    {
        list.ForEach(each =>
        {
            if (each > 2)
            {
                throw new LocalReturnException(each);
            }
            WriteLine(each);
        });
    }
    catch (LocalReturnException e)
    {
        return e.Value;
    }

    return 5;
}

class LocalReturnException : Exception
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public LocalReturnException(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Because the `List<T>.ForEach()` method does not provide any mechanism to interrupt its enumeration of the source enumerable, the only way to get the method to return prematurely is to bypass the normal method-returning mechanisms by throwing an exception.

Of course, exceptions are fairly heavy-weight. There's a marginal cost just for the `try`/`catch` handler, and actually throwing and catching one is *very* costly. If you have a need for this idiom, it would be better to create your own enumeration method which provides for a mechanism to interrupt the enumeration and return a value. For example, create extension methods like so:

```
public static T? InterruptableForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T?> action)
   where T : struct
{
    foreach (T t in source)
    {
        T? result = action(t);

        if (result != null) return result;
    }

    return null;
}

public static T InterruptableForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T> action)
    where T : class
{
    foreach (T t in source)
    {
        T result = action(t);

        if (result != null) return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The first is needed for your example. I show two, because C# treats value types like `int` differently from reference types when it comes to `null` values, but the second isn't strictly needed here.

With the extension method, you can then do something like this:

```
static int foo()
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    var result = list.InterruptableForEach(each =>
    {
        if (each > 2)
        {
            return each;
        }
        WriteLine(each);
        return null;
    });

    return result ?? 5;
}
```

Note that the caller needs to cooperate with the lambda and the extension method. That is, the extension method is explicitly reporting what the lambda itself returned, so that it knows whether the lambda returned prematurely and if so, what the value is.

On the one hand, this is a bit more clumsy and verbose than the Scala version. On the other hand, it's consistent with C#'s tendency toward explicitness and expressiveness, and avoidance of ambiguous situations (such as, what if the `foo()` method didn't return an `int`, but the lambda did?).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025420) shows yet another possible approach. I personally would prefer either of the above, as they both actually *interrupt* the enumeration, rather than just skip the main lambda body until the end of the enumeration (which could be a problem for infinite enumerations), and don't introduce the additional captured variables required by that answer. But it does work in your example.

Comment: Your idea with LocalReturnException is also what Scala is doing. That is in Scala the compiler does the plumbing work for LocalReturnException. The user is not aware of this, because the compiler does the waeving transparently. Problem is that non-local returns cannot be done on the JVM. Kotlin for the JVM takes a different approach through inlining, e.g. the compiler transforms the code to a solution that works without non-local returns. This is not always doable, but for the important use cases in daily developer life it appears to work well.

Answer (score 0):

this are my answers to your questions:

1)
You dont need to install anything for playing arround with C# and LINQ. You can simply use https://dotnetfiddle.net

2) Here is my code https://dotnetfiddle.net/3V8vBj

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public class Program
{

    static int foo()
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int ret = 5;
        bool keepGoing = true;
        list.ForEach(each =>
                 {
                    if (!keepGoing)
                         return;
                     if (each>2)
                     {
                        ret=each;
                        keepGoing = false;
                        return;
                     }

                     System.Console.WriteLine(each);

                 });
        return ret;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = foo();
        System.Console.WriteLine("i: " + i);

    }
}
```

3) When you using LINQ Foreach you can not simply break it for return, since it is a delegate function. So I had to implement keepGoing.

4) The nested delegate function can not return a value, so I have to use "ret" for setting the return inside the LINQ Foreach.

I hope this answers your question, but I am not really sure that I understand it right.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The workaround with keepGoing makes it clear that in case of a closure a return has the effect of a continue. So this means that C# closures do not support non-local returns. That's a pitty. I was hoping for C# to be better here than Java8 lambdas.